# how to animate a bubble like the one in the discord login page?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, discord

I tried playing with simplex noise and bezier curves, but I couldn't get the same smooth bubble as the one in the [discord login page](https://discordapp.com/login).

Finally I settled for [this](https://codepen.io/soufiane-yakoubi/full/YzPGXZL), since it's the closest I got to the desired result, but it still doesn't feel as smooth as discord's.

I divided the 90 degrees arc into steps, and for every step I'll pick a radius value using the sine wave which I control using its frequency and phase, then connect all the points created with the `curve` function ([credit](https://www.npm.red/package/cardinal-spline-js)).

Does anyone know exactly how that bubble is made?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty difficult to dig out the actual implementation from their minified javascript, however for educational purposes only (because this code may be protected by copyright, so I don't suggest you try to make this function verbatim on any other site), here is the javascript that appears to implement this animation:

```
function(e, t, n) {
        "use strict";
        t.__esModule = !0,
        t.default = void 0;
        var r = function(e) {
            if (e && e.__esModule)
                return e;
            var t = {};
            if (null != e)
                for (var n in e)
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, n)) {
                        var r = Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e, n) : {};
                        r.get || r.set ? Object.defineProperty(t, n, r) : t[n] = e[n]
                    }
            return t.default = e,
            t
        }(n(0))
          , a = n(88)
          , i = n(105)
          , o = p(n(9308))
          , s = p(n(9310))
          , l = p(n(9313))
          , u = n(6856)
          , d = n(1)
          , c = p(n(6126))
          , f = p(n(5546));
        function p(e) {
            return e && e.__esModule ? e : {
                default: e
            }
        }
        var v = (0,
        i.cssValueToNumber)(f.default.responsiveWidthMobile)
          , h = 1 / 120
          , m = 4e3
          , _ = function(e) {
            var t, n;
            function i(t) {
                var n;
                return (n = e.call(this, t) || this).width = 0,
                n.height = 0,
                n.children = [],
                n.ratio = 0,
                n._lastTick = 0,
                n._isPlaying = !1,
                n._reqAnimId = null,
                n.setCanvas = function(e) {
                    if (null != e) {
                        n.canvas = e,
                        n.canvasContext = n.canvas.getContext("2d");
                        var t = window.devicePixelRatio || 1
                          , r = n.canvasContext.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio || n.canvasContext.mozBackingStorePixelRatio || n.canvasContext.msBackingStorePixelRatio || n.canvasContext.oBackingStorePixelRatio || n.canvasContext.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;
                        n.ratio = t / r
                    }
                }
                ,
                n.resizeCanvas = function() {
                    n.width = window.innerWidth,
                    n.height = window.innerHeight;
                    var e = function(e) {
                        if (void 0 === e)
                            throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");
                        return e
                    }(n)
                      , t = e.canvas
                      , r = e.canvasContext
                      , a = e.width
                      , i = e.height
                      , o = e.ratio;
                    null != t && null != r && (t.width = a * o,
                    t.height = i * o,
                    t.style.width = a + "px",
                    t.style.height = i + "px",
                    r.scale(o, o)),
                    a <= v ? n.pause() : n.play(),
                    n.wave.resizeWave(),
                    n.renderAnimation()
                }
                ,
                n.handleVisibilityChange = function() {
                    document.hidden ? n.delayedPause() : n.play()
                }
                ,
                n.play = function() {
                    clearTimeout(n._pauseTimeout),
                    n._isPlaying || (n._isPlaying = !0,
                    n.run())
                }
                ,
                n.pause = function() {
                    clearTimeout(n._pauseTimeout),
                    n._isPlaying = !1,
                    window.cancelAnimationFrame(n._reqAnimId),
                    n._reqAnimId = null,
                    n.advanceTransitionalState()
                }
                ,
                n.delayedPause = function() {
                    clearTimeout(n._pauseTimeout),
                    n._pauseTimeout = setTimeout(n.pause, m)
                }
                ,
                n.updateWaveState = function(e) {
                    (0,
                    n.props.updateWaveState)(e)
                }
                ,
                n.handleWaveEmphasize = function() {
                    n.wave.emphasize()
                }
                ,
                n.run = function() {
                    if (n._isPlaying) {
                        if (0 === n._lastTick)
                            return n._lastTick = Date.now(),
                            void (n._reqAnimId = requestAnimationFrame(n.run));
                        for (var e = Date.now(), t = Math.min((e - n._lastTick) / 1e3, 8 * h); t > 0; ) {
                            var r = t < h ? t : h;
                            n.updateAnimation(r),
                            t -= r
                        }
                        n.renderAnimation(),
                        n._lastTick = e,
                        n._reqAnimId = requestAnimationFrame(n.run)
                    }
                }
                ,
                n.wave = new l.default(n.updateWaveState),
                n.children = [new o.default, new s.default, n.wave],
                n
            }
            n = e,
            (t = i).prototype = Object.create(n.prototype),
            t.prototype.constructor = t,
            t.__proto__ = n;
            var f = i.prototype;
            return f.componentDidMount = function() {
                this.initialize()
            }
            ,
            f.componentDidUpdate = function(e) {
                var t = this.props.waveState;
                t === u.WaveStates.FILLING && t !== e.waveState && this.waveFill()
            }
            ,
            f.componentWillUnmount = function() {
                this.terminate()
            }
            ,
            f.initialize = function() {
                this.children.forEach(function(e) {
                    return e.initialize()
                }),
                this.bindEvents(),
                this.resizeCanvas(),
                document.hidden && this.delayedPause()
            }
            ,
            f.terminate = function() {
                this.pause(),
                this.unbindEvents(),
                this.children.forEach(function(e) {
                    return e.terminate()
                })
            }
            ,
            f.bindEvents = function() {
                window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeCanvas, !1),
                window.addEventListener("blur", this.delayedPause, !1),
                window.addEventListener("focus", this.play, !1),
                document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", this.handleVisibilityChange, !1),
                a.ComponentDispatch.subscribe(d.ComponentActions.WAVE_EMPHASIZE, this.handleWaveEmphasize)
            }
            ,
            f.unbindEvents = function() {
                window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resizeCanvas, !1),
                window.removeEventListener("blur", this.delayedPause, !1),
                window.removeEventListener("focus", this.play, !1),
                document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", this.handleVisibilityChange, !1),
                a.ComponentDispatch.unsubscribe(d.ComponentActions.WAVE_EMPHASIZE, this.handleWaveEmphasize)
            }
            ,
            f.advanceTransitionalState = function() {
                var e = this.props.waveState;
                e !== u.WaveStates.INITIAL && e !== u.WaveStates.FILLING || this.updateWaveState(e + 1)
            }
            ,
            f.waveFill = function() {
                this._isPlaying ? this.children.forEach(function(e) {
                    return e.fill()
                }) : this.updateWaveState(u.WaveStates.FILLED)
            }
            ,
            f.updateAnimation = function(e) {
                this.children.forEach(function(t) {
                    return t.update(e)
                })
            }
            ,
            f.renderAnimation = function() {
                var e = this.canvasContext;
                null != e && (e.fillStyle = d.Colors.PRIMARY_DARK_630,
                e.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height),
                this.children.forEach(function(t) {
                    return t.render(e)
                }))
            }
            ,
            f.render = function() {
                return r.createElement("canvas", {
                    className: c.default.canvas,
                    ref: this.setCanvas
                })
            }
            ,
            i
        }(r.Component);
        _.displayName = "WaveAnimation";
        var g = _;
        t.default = g
    }
```

One of WaveAnimation's children is Wave:

```
function(e, t, n) {
        "use strict";
        t.__esModule = !0,
        t.default = void 0;
        var r = u(n(542))
          , a = n(105)
          , i = u(n(9314))
          , o = n(7355)
          , s = n(6856)
          , l = u(n(5546));
        function u(e) {
            return e && e.__esModule ? e : {
                default: e
            }
        }
        var d = 15
          , c = d / 2
          , f = (0,
        a.cssValueToNumber)(l.default.responsiveWidthMobile);
        function p(e, t, n, r) {
            return t * (n / r) + e
        }
        function v() {
            return Math.min(Math.max(Math.min(.8 * window.innerWidth, .8 * window.innerHeight), s.MIN_RADIUS), s.MAX_RADIUS)
        }
        var h = 30
          , m = function() {
            function e(e) {
                var t, n = this;
                this.points = [],
                this.hasEntered = !1,
                this.isFilling = !1,
                this._resizeWave = function() {
                    var e = v();
                    n.points.forEach(function(t, n) {
                        var r = e * Math.cos(s.TWO_PI * p(0, .25, n, d)) - 40
                          , a = e * Math.sin(s.TWO_PI * p(0, .25, n, d)) - 40;
                        0 !== n ? a += (0,
                        o.randomNumber)(0, h) - h / 2 : n !== d && (r += (0,
                        o.randomNumber)(0, h) - h / 2),
                        t.targetX = r,
                        t.targetY = a,
                        t.angle = Math.atan2(a, r)
                    })
                }
                ,
                this.resizeWave = (0,
                r.default)(this._resizeWave, 200),
                this.updateWaveState = e,
                this.hasEntered = !1;
                for (var a = 0; a <= d; a++)
                    this.points.push(new i.default((t = a,
                    Math.floor(c - Math.floor(Math.abs(t - c))))))
            }
            var t = e.prototype;
            return t.initialize = function() {
                this._resizeWave()
            }
            ,
            t.emphasize = function() {
                this.points.forEach(function(e) {
                    return e.speedUp = 1
                })
            }
            ,
            t.terminate = function() {
                this.points = []
            }
            ,
            // ***** This updates the individual points over time, see the next code block *****
            t.update = function(e) {
                0 !== this.points.length && (this.points.forEach(function(t) {
                    return t.update(Math.min(e, 1 / 60))
                }),
                this.hasEntered || this.points[0].x > f && (this.hasEntered = !0,
                this.updateWaveState(s.WaveStates.ENTERED)),
                this.isFilling && this.points[0].x > this.points[0].targetX && (this.isFilling = !1,
                this.updateWaveState(s.WaveStates.FILLED)))
            }
            ,
            t.render = function(e) {
                // ***** This is the code that actually draws the curve pasted on the array of points *****
                if (0 !== this.points.length) {
                    var t = this.points
                      , n = t[0]
                      , r = t.slice(1);
                    e.save(),
                    e.beginPath(),
                    e.moveTo(n.x, n.y),
                    r.forEach(function(t, n) {
                        if (null == r[n + 1])
                            e.quadraticCurveTo(t.x, t.y, t.x, t.y);
                        else {
                            var a = (t.x + r[n + 1].x) / 2
                              , i = (t.y + r[n + 1].y) / 2;
                            e.quadraticCurveTo(t.x, t.y, a, i)
                        }
                    }),
                    e.lineTo(0, 0),
                    e.closePath(),
                    e.fillStyle = "#000",
                    e.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in",
                    e.fill(),
                    e.restore()
                }
            }
            ,
            t.fill = function() {
                var e = this
                  , t = Math.sqrt(window.innerWidth * window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight * window.innerHeight) + 100
                  , n = v() - 140
                  , r = function(e, t, n, r) {
                    e.targetX = t * Math.cos(s.TWO_PI * p(0, .25, n, d)) - 40,
                    e.targetY = t * Math.sin(s.TWO_PI * p(0, .25, n, d)) - 40,
                    r && (e.targetX += (0,
                    o.randomNumber)(0, h) - h / 2,
                    e.targetY += (0,
                    o.randomNumber)(0, h) - h / 2,
                    e.speedUp = 3,
                    e.spring.tension = s.POINT_TENSION_DEFAULT * Math.random() * .5 + s.POINT_TENSION_DEFAULT)
                };
                this.points.forEach(function(e, t) {
                    return r(e, n, t, !0)
                }),
                setTimeout(function() {
                    e.points.forEach(function(e, n) {
                        r(e, t, n, !1);
                        var a = 1 - e.index / (d / 2);
                        e.spring.friction += e.spring.friction + e.spring.friction * a,
                        e.spring.tension = .7 * s.POINT_TENSION_DEFAULT + 80 * Math.random(),
                        e.waveRange = 2 * e.waveRange
                    }),
                    e.isFilling = !0,
                    e.updateWaveState(s.WaveStates.FILLING)
                }, 250)
            }
            ,
            e
        }();
        m.displayName = "Wave";
        var _ = m;
        t.default = _
    }
```

The Wave's points are animated with this code:

```
function(e, t, n) {
        "use strict";
        t.__esModule = !0,
        t.default = void 0;
        var r = n(7355)
          , a = n(6856)
          , i = 60
          , o = 2.15 * Math.cos(Math.PI)
          , s = function() {
            function e(e) {
                this.x = -40,
                this.y = -40,
                this.targetX = 0,
                this.targetY = 0,
                this.oscillate = !0,
                this.velX = 0,
                this.velY = 0,
                this.angle = 0,
                this.speedUp = 1.5,
                this.waveRange = i,
                this.spring = {
                    friction: 15,
                    tension: a.POINT_TENSION_DEFAULT
                },
                this.index = e,
                this.spring.tension = a.POINT_TENSION_DEFAULT * Math.max(.1, e / 7) + a.POINT_TENSION_DEFAULT,
                this.count = o * e
            }
            var t = e.prototype;
            return t.updateStatic = function() {
                this.targetX = this.targetX + 30 * Math.cos(this.angle) * Math.sin(this.count),
                this.targetY = this.targetY + 30 * Math.sin(this.angle) * Math.sin(this.count),
                this.x = this.targetX,
                this.y = this.targetY
            }
            ,
            // ***** This is the point updating animation code ***
            t.update = function(e) {
                var t, n;
                if (this.speedUp > 0 ? (this.speedUp = Math.max(0, this.speedUp - e),
                this.count += e * (10 * Math.min(this.speedUp, 1) + .4)) : this.count += .4 * e,
                t = (0,
                r.applySpringForce)(this.targetX, this.x, this.velX, this.spring),
                n = (0,
                r.applySpringForce)(this.targetY, this.y, this.velY, this.spring),
                this.velX += t * e,
                this.velY += n * e,
                this.oscillate) {
                    var a = this.targetX + this.waveRange * Math.cos(this.angle) * Math.sin(this.count)
                      , i = this.targetY + this.waveRange * Math.sin(this.angle) * Math.sin(this.count);
                    t = (0,
                    r.applySpringForce)(a, this.x, this.velX, this.spring),
                    n = (0,
                    r.applySpringForce)(i, this.y, this.velY, this.spring),
                    this.velX += t * e,
                    this.velY += n * e
                }
                this.x += this.velX * e,
                this.y += this.velY * e
            }
            ,
            t.render = function(e) {
                e.fillStyle = "#fff",
                e.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 4, 4)
            }
            ,
            e
        }();
        s.displayName = "Point";
        var l = s;
        t.default = l
    }
```

As you can see this code is fairly unreadable and I wouldn't be able to reproduce its functionality without a lot more work. All of this javascript was found in https://discordapp.com/assets/7fa6862ce32bc7ec4838.js but be aware that the filename is likely to change if/when the deploy a new version of their login page.

Comment: i did go through this code , but it seems that i lack knowledge about how es modules work , so i guess I'm spending some time learning it .